# How to get value from dataTable of a column that has a dropdownlist control in the gridview?in row updating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

How can I get the value from data table of the gridview for a specific column where the control is a dropdownlist.So I don't want to get the dropdownlist value I want to get the value for the column that is set in the datatable.

I need it in row updating event

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include some code? It's very difficult to assess the question as is.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the dbms can only be different if the user has changed it, so either select it from dbms again or - better - use the [`OldValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) `Dictionary` from `GridViewUpdateEventArgs`.

```
void GridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    String fieldName = "FooColumn";
    Object oldValue = e.OldValues[fieldName];
}
```

> The OldValues property is automatically populated with the original
>   values of all the field name/value pairs in the row. A separate entry
>   is added to the OldValues property for each field in the row.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Alexander: That's the message of a famous exception type. What is `null`, have you changed `FooColumn` to the correct field name?

Comment: ofc I've changed , I've tried Label2.Text = oldValue.ToString(); to check if I can get it..and it didn't worked. The colum value is not null

Comment: @Alexander: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at this line and inspect the values of e.OldValues in the quick-watch window. The Dictionary is populated only with declarative datasource controls like ObjectDataSource and **SqlDataSource**, hence it should work for you.